# Pass bundle between three Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I have three Fragments and one object which I need to pass from first to second and then to third fragment.

First:

```
 ArrayList<Article> list = app.getDb().getArticles("userId", app.getUser(getActivity()).getId(),
                "id", item.getId());
        FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ArticleFragment mFrag = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("article", list.get(0));
        mFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFrag, ArticleFragment.TAG);
        t.addToBackStack(ArticleFragment.TAG);
        t.commit();
```

Second:

```
 article = getArguments().getParcelable("article");
// some actions
 ArticleEditFragment mFrag = new ArticleEditFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("article_edit", article);
                mFrag.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFrag, ArticleEditFragment.TAG);
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                t.commit();
```

Third:

```
article = getArguments().getParcelable("article_edit");
//some actions with article
```

The problem is article changing when I finish third fragment and return to second. The second contains the same object that I edited in third fragment. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve for me was creating my own 'Clone' method in Article class.

```
        incomeArticle = getArguments().getParcelable("article_edit");
        article = incomeArticle.cloneArticle();


 /**
         * Clone all field of current article to new
         *
         * @return new article
         */
        public Article cloneArticle() {
            Article article = new Article();
            article.setName(this.name);
            article.setId(this.id);
            article.setUserId(this.userId);
            article.setTypeId(this.typeId);
            article.setPictureId(this.pictureId);
            article.setAccess(this.access);
            if (this.pictures != null) {
                article.setPictures((ArrayList<String>) this.pictures.clone());
            } else {
                article.setPictures(new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            article.setComments(this.comments);
            if (this.tags != null) {
                article.setTags((ArrayList<String>) this.tags.clone());
            } else {
                article.setTags(new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            if (this.care != null) {
                article.setCare((ArrayList<String>) this.care.clone());
            } else {
                article.setCare(new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            article.setFitLevel(this.fitLevel);
            article.setRating(this.rating);
            if (this.materials != null) {
                article.setMaterials((ArrayList<ArticleMaterial>) this.materials.clone());
            } else {
                article.setMaterials(new ArrayList<ArticleMaterial>());
            }
            article.setBuyingDate(this.buyingDate);
            article.setSize(this.size);
            article.setArticul(this.articul);
            article.setPrice(this.price);
            article.setMadeInCountryId(this.madeInCountryId);
            article.setCurrencyId(this.currencyId);
            article.setCommentsCount(this.commentsCount);
            article.setToWeight(this.toWeight);
            article.setBrandId(this.brandId);
            article.setChanged(this.changed);
            article.setShowWeight(this.showWeight);
            article.setCreated(this.created);
            article.setDescription(this.description);
            article.setIsLiked(this.isLiked);
            article.setLikeRating(this.likeRating);
            article.setFromWeight(this.fromWeight);
            article.setGuid(this.guid);
            return article;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `First` fragment you have passed the value in bundle as `articles_list` and in your second you are getting it as `article` which should be `articles_list` . So change it as below in your `Second` fragment as below:

Change the below line :

```
 article = getArguments().getParcelable("article");
```

To

```
 article = getArguments().getParcelable("articles_list");
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Please your error in your question.

Comment: I don't have error message in application. The problem is article object. When I change it in third fragment and returning to second, the article from second fragment was changet also. I want avoid this and change only article from third fragment.

Comment: You just pass the bundle with different name in your and change it in your third fragment with different value and get it into the second fragment in another parcelable instance.

Comment: But how to pass clone of this article not the original object?

Answer (score -1):

make changes 
In second fragment

```
article = new  Article(getArguments().getParcelable("article"));
```

in third fragment

```
article = new  Article(getArguments().getParcelable("articles_list"));
```

and in your article pojo create a constructor

```
Article(Article A1)
{
value1=A1.value1;
value2=A1.value2;
value3=A1.value3;
...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ArrayList hasn't such constructor.

Comment: pls go and check in net first ...there is a constructor ArrayList(Collection c)..

Comment: I talk only for my case. How can I get ArrayList<Article> from arguments if I put there only Article object? But in general this constructor is exist.